# Option twoside not working

Tags: double-sided, documentclass

I am trying to get the twoside-option for documentclass to work. But I am facing a couple of problems:

1. There is no empty page after the title page
2. while the spacing does alternate between left and right, the page numbering does not

I have no clue where the problem might be, if more information is needed let me know

```
documentclass[openright,twoside,a4paper,12pt,headsepline]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fix-cm}

\usepackage{longtable}


\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=3.5cm, right=2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm}

\usepackage{fancybox}

\usepackage[hyphens,obeyspaces,spaces]{url}

\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\input{latex_einstellungen/variablen}

\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered,pdftitle={\titleDocument},hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref} 

\usepackage{fancyhdr} %Paket laden
\pagestyle{fancy} %eigener Seitenstil
\fancyhf{} %alle Kopf- und Fußzeilenfelder bereinigen
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}} %Kopfzeile links
\fancyhead[C]{} %zentrierte Kopfzeile
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage} %Kopfzeile rechts
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt} %obere Trennlinie

\usepackage{array}

\frenchspacing

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{capt-of}

\usepackage{makeidx}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, numbersep=5pt, keywordstyle=\color{black}\bfseries, stringstyle=\ttfamily,showstringspaces=false,basicstyle=\footnotesize,captionpos=b}
\lstset{language=java}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \input{latex_einstellungen/trennung}

    \include{titlepage}

    \onehalfspacing

    \include{abstract}

    \singlespacing

    \newpage
    \tableofcontents

    \newpage
    \fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}} %Kopfzeile links

    \onehalfspacing

    \input{1_einleitung}

    \input{2_grundlagen}

    \input{3_entwicklung_strategie}

    \input{4_training}

    \input{5_evaluierung}

    \input{6_fazit_ausblick}

    \onecolumn
    \singlespacing
    \newpage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Literaturverzeichnis}
    \renewcommand\refname{Literaturverzeichnis}
    \bibliographystyle{alphadin}
    \bibliography{bibliography}

    \onehalfspacing
    \newpage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Anhang}
    \fancyhead[L]{Anhang} %Kopfzeile links
    \input{anhang/anhang}

    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Eidesstattliche Erklärung}
    \include{erklaerung}

    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{empty
    \section*{ }

\end{document}
```

Comment: no one can run your example to see your issue as it includes files not provide, it is far more useful to make a small self contained example that shows the issue. I don't know scrartcl that well but I suspect that you should be using its build in support for setting the page head rather than using `fancyhdr` but `\fancyhead[R]{\thepage} %Kopfzeile rechts` is putting the page number at the right hand side of all pages.

Comment: yea, I am a bit pressed for time right now, so I was hoping someone could figure out by the preamble, which you did! With that hint I was able to find the answer by myself (using the options LO, RE for \fancyhead to toggle the pages). Thanks a lot! (if you would like to turn that into an answer, feel free to do so, I will mark it as correct)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage} %Kopfzeile rechts
```

is putting the page number at the right hand side of all pages.

you can use `LO` to specify left on odd pages, `RO`, `RE` etc.

Note also that the koma-script classes have their own facilities for page headings and (I think) fancyhdr is not recommended here, although it should work in most cases.

Comment: @barbarabeeton er yes, You could edit it:-) thanks, I'll fix.